# MySql: query optimization or table's structure optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I need some help with mysql.

Let's show you. I have two tables: `nodes`(250 000 rows):
`id | name`

And table `groups`(~400 000 rows):
`id | group_id | node_id` - index(node_id) and maybe index(group_id)

Problem query:
`select count(*) from nodes n inner join groups g on g.node_id = n.id  \
where g.group_id in (1,20, 30...);`
Execution time: **0.50 sec** and it's problem for me.

How I can optimize query to count rows and then make select?
Where I can put index or new field for benefit?

Comment: Is there any index on the joined columns?

Comment: Use explain to find out where you need an `index`

Comment: Madhivanan, yes.  index(node_id)

Comment: You perhaps need an index as `alter table groups add index gid_nid_idx(group_id,node_id)`, make sure take a backup before applying index.

Answer (score 0):

```
`SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table
```

Don't bother with an `id` for a many-to-many table.  Do be sure to have indexes going both ways in such a table.

Why does your Problem Query need to touch `nodes` at all?  This will count the number of nodes in each group, won't it?

```
SELECT  group_id,
        COUNT(*)
    FROM groups
    WHERE group_id IN (...)
    GROUP BY group_id;
```

`groups`:  `PRIMARY KEY(group_id, node_id)`, `INDEX(node_id, group_id)`

If that is not what you are looking for, please describe the query.